Lost assets after deleting the account
I'm not sure this is the correct way to contact. I accidentally deleted my one account from the Metaskwask wallet and when I recovered my account with my secret phrase I couldn't find some of the assets. I have XIO and FLASH tokens from the old account but the new one recovered the account doesn't have that one.
I used to have more than one account in my Metamadk wallet but I couldn't find that one too.
Can someone please help me here to find the solution? I’m really helpless at the moment.

Blockchain assets don’t disappear when you “delete” your account from a wallet ie. Metamask,
I suggest you add the networks to the wallet again

Maybe you just didn't import the tokens?
Follow the guide below to display your desired tokens in Metamask.
https://support.metamask.io/managing-my-tokens/custom-tokens/how-to-display-tokens-in-metamask/
